# Using AND condition in Batch file causes trouble

Tags: conditional-statements, batch-file, execution

In a batch file I have

```
findstr SWITCHIDENTITY rf_monitor.out >nul 2>&1 && set IDENTITY_FOUND=true
findstr SWITCHUTILITY rf_monitor.out >nul 2>&1 && set UTILITY_FOUND=true
findstr "GP Manager connection successful" rf_monitor.out >nul 2>&1 && set GPMANAGER_FOUND=true
```

with echo on, below is what I see

```
D:\cvstags\trunk\regfortcms\install\win\scripts>findstr SWITCHIDENTITY rf_monito
r.out   1>nul 2>&1  && set IDENTITY_FOUND=true

D:\cvstags\trunk\regfortcms\install\win\scripts>findstr SWITCHUTILITY rf_monitor
.out   1>nul 2>&1  && set UTILITY_FOUND=true

D:\cvstags\trunk\regfortcms\install\win\scripts>findstr "GP Manager connection s
uccessful" rf_monitor.out   1>nul 2>&1  && set GPMANAGER_FOUND=true

**&& was unexpected at this time.**
```

Why do I get that `&& was unexpected at this time`? If I type the three commands myself on the DOS prompt I don't get any such message. Please advice.

Comment: If it's really DOS, then you're out of luck. Do you mean the Windows Command Interpreter (aka `cmd.exe`)? Which OS?

Comment: Yes its the cmd.exe also called DOS prompt. I'm using Windows xp.

Answer (score 2):

Goddammit, the error message had been not about the lines I posted but about my usage of && in an IF condition. It seems that I have to use like IF condition1 IF condition2 .